# Formula for Nested Loops with Dependence

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Big O: Nested For Loop With Dependence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326708/big-o-nested-for-loop-with-dependence)

Given the following nested loops, I have to figure out the Big O complexity of it:

```
for(i=0 to n)
    for(j=n-1;j>=i;j--)
```

I know that the complexity of this will be `O(n^2)`, but I am unsure of how to figure out the formula for the inner loop.

I wrote out a table, for clarity:

```
n=10
i | j | outer iters | inner iters
0 | 9 |     1       |     10
1 | 9 |     2       |      9 
...
9 | 9 |    10       |      1
```

Therefore, the outer loop runs `n` times, while the inner runs `sum(n to n-9)`.

I was told the answer was `n(n-2)/2`, and I simply can't figure out how to get from what I have, to this conclusion.

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that the answer you were told is wrong (at least for the code you posted). Take a look at @krjampani's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Observe the number of times the inner loop gets executed for each iteration of the outer-loop.

```
When i=0, the inner loop has n iterations.
When i=1, the inner loop has n-1 iterations.
When i=2, the inner loop has n-2 iterations.
......
When i=k, the inner loop has n-k iterations.
.....
When i=n-2, the inner loop has 2 iterations.
When i=n-1, the inner loop has 1 iterations.
```

So the total number of iterations of the inner loop is 1 + 2 + ... + (n-2) + (n-1) + n, which is equal to n(n+1)/2.

Comment: Interesting that the answer comes out different from what OP was told is the correct answer. :)

Comment: So, wouldn't that then mean that the total runtime would be:
n*((n^2+n)/2) = O(n^3)?

Comment: The TOTAL number of inner iterations is n(n+1)/2. So the total number of times we will do any computation in the inner loop is n(n+1)/2. The outer loop runs for n iterations. So the total running time is n + n(n+1)/2 = O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

for 1st iteration -- inner loop n-1times
for 2nd iteration -- inner loop n-2 times
so on

for n-1 iteration -- inner loop 1 time

total number of iterations = (n-1)+(n-2)+..2+1 =n(n-1)/2

which is n^2-n/2 which is ofcourse O(n^2)
since we can write it as 
if f(n)= n^2-n/2
and g(n)=n^2

We can write it write it as 
0<=f(n)<=c.g(n)
for c>0 n0>0 
here n greater than n0

Comment: Look again. On the first iteration (i == 0), the inner loop runs from j=n-1 down to _and including_ j=0, for a total of n times, not n-1.

Answer (score 1):

Summing the integers 1 to n is the well known Trick of Gauss:

[image: gauss's trick]
<sub>(note that it is `+ 1`, not `- 2`)</sub>

### Building an intuition

Here is an intuitive way to see why this formula is true:

[image: explanation]

Try to see it for yourself with `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6`

### Proving our intuition

But what if don't have an even number of terms? Does it still work? Does it work for any number of terms? To answer this, we best prove our
**Hypothesis**:

[image: hypothesis]
with a concept called mathematical induction.
For this, we first need to establish a base case, in this case for `n = 1`, this is trivially correct.

Now, for the **inductive step**. We assume, that we have already proven our hypothesis for some `n`, based on this knowledge, we want to show that it also holds for `n + 1`. If this succeeds, we have "magically" proven it for all natural numbers. **Why?** We have already shown it to work for `n = 1`, the `n => n + 1` step means it is now proven for `n = 2`, which means it's also proven for `n = 3` etc. It's a domino effect, tipping over the first will let all others fall (prove).

[image: inductive step]

Substituting `n` with `n + 1` in the hypothesis gives us the result of our inductive step. Thus, we have proven the formula correct for all `n`.